# Php code that is like a public variable in java?

Tags: php, variables

MYSQL DATA: table schedule

```
ID | Subject | Day | Slot
1  | Math    | MWF | 1
2  | Math    | MWF | 0
3  | PE      | TTH | 2
4  | Math    | Sat | 0
```

In the Data above I already get how to subtract the slot to 1 when I ADD Schedule to the student and now I already Confucius when I Delete the Schedule on the student the slot will also update to + 1 to specific subject. I just use the same variable that i use in ADD schedule  and i just change the - sign to + sign to add, When I run my code my variable is undefined I use one page only.

Code for update the slot for add schedule then subtract the slot:

```
textslot = $_post['txtslot'];<br>
textwholenumber = $_post['wholenumber'];<br>
$sql = "UPDATE schedule ". "SET Slot = $textslot - $textwholenumber".  "WHERE Subject = '$textsubject' and Day = '$textday'";
```

Code for update the slot for delete schedule then add the slot:

```
$sql = "UPDATE schedule ". "SET Slot = $textslot + $textwholenumber".  "WHERE Subject = '$textsubject' and Day = '$textday'";
```

the `$textslot` and `$textwholenumber` in the delete code is undefined?

Comment: On my post i just add

Comment: I been working for it. But i couldn't update the specific data subject slot for schedule after i delete the subject taken it only add the first row of the schedule even I delete all the subject taken all the +1 was added to the first schedule subject list. <br> I was thinkin about if its possible to session or show the delete subject like for example i delete the PE TTH 2 subject and it will  echo you have delete the PE THH 2. How to make it possible that was the solution that come up on my mind but i don't know how to do it.. help\

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to prefix variable name with the `$` symbol to declare a variable, try this;

   ```
   $textslot = $_POST['txtslot'];
   $textwholenumber = $_POST['wholenumber'];
   ```
2. The `<br>` elements are not valid PHP, end the PHP code with the
       closing `?>` or use the `echo` function to output these linebreaks. I suspect you don't need them at all, try removing them altogether.
3. Read up on [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php), your SQL statement is exposed to
       this. Try parametised queries to overcome this.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I been working for it. But i couldn't update the specific data subject slot for schedule after i delete the subject taken it only add the first row of the schedule even I delete all the subject taken all the +1 was added to the first schedule subject list. <br> I was thinkin about if its possible to session or show the delete subject like for example i delete the PE TTH 2 subject and it will  echo you have delete the PE THH 2. How to make it possible that was the solution that come up on my mind but i don't know how to do it.. help\

Comment: Add all the code you're using by editing your question if you still need some help - its hard to understand what you need without it